# NSTextField text not showing

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to draw a text with background color and border radius, but the text does not show.

I've used `sizeToFit` to make the textfield fit its content.

When the below code is added to its superview, this is what is shown:

[image]

As you can see, the text is missing even though the view has adjusted itself to fit the text. I have tried setting a huge frame but its the same issue.

```
    let text = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    text.stringValue = "ABC"
    text.sizeToFit()
    text.wantsLayer = true
    text.isBordered = true
    text.drawsBackground = true

    let textFieldLayer = CALayer()
    text.layer = textFieldLayer
    text.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue
    text.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
    text.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
    text.layer?.borderWidth = 1
    text.layer?.cornerRadius = 5
    text.textColor = NSColor.red

    let positionRelativeToScreen = toOrigin(point: positionFlipped, size: text.frame.size)
    let positionRelativeToWindow = borderWindow.convertPoint(fromScreen: positionRelativeToScreen)
    text.frame.origin = positionRelativeToWindow
    return text
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift NSTextField text disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396370/swift-nstextfield-text-disappears)

Comment: @Willeke yup. works after I deleted textFieldLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to remove `textFieldLayer`. Thanks @Willeke!